# keydown event not getting caught in react unless I cause a re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, rendering, react-to-print

I'm trying to print specific components of my app using [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) library. I'm trying to override the event of pressing `ctrl+p` for printing by using `event.preventDefault()` and it's working for the first time that is when the app renders, on ctrl+p the required components are getting printed but after this the second time I click ctrl+p is not getting caught inside my `handleKeyDown` function, instead the browser default of printing the entire page is happening.

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";

const Example = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });

  const handleKeyDown = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      console.log("keydown");
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "p") {
        event.preventDefault();
        handlePrint();
      }
    },
    [handlePrint]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [handleKeyDown]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={componentRef}>
        <div>Div 1</div>
        <div>Div 2</div>
        <div>Div 3</div>
      </div>
      <div>Div not printed</div>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

The ctrl+p gives the desired result the first time after every re-render but on further tries its not working. I'm assuming the issue to be with the `keyDown` event not getting caught after causing the print for the first time.

How can I get it to work properly so that ctrl+p prints the desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. What happened was, when the print dialogue opened, the focus from the app was somehow lost (not sure) until I manually clicked on the screen/app component and `ctrl+p` worked as desired.

```
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    onAfterPrint: () => {
      document.activeElement.blur();
      componentRef.current.focus();
    },
  });
```

Just modifying the `handlePrint` function and taking the focus back on the component worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for the event on the document object, you can try utilising the window object to catch the keydown event at a higher level in your component hierarchy to resolve this problem. In this manner, the event will be recorded regardless of the app's current focus.

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";

const Example = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });

  const handleKeyDown = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      console.log("keydown");
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "p") {
        event.preventDefault();
        handlePrint();
      }
    },
    [handlePrint]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown); // Use window object instead of document
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown); // Use window object instead of document
    };
  }, [handleKeyDown]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={componentRef}>
        <div>Div 1</div>
        <div>Div 2</div>
        <div>Div 3</div>
      </div>
      <div>Div not printed</div>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

You should be able to reliably capture Ctrl+P keydown events and cause the desired printing behaviour even after the first print by leveraging the window object to capture the keydown event.

Comment: Not working. Unable to get the console.log("keyDown") on clicking the second time